# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2) {_id: 6414a040c01cb2fbea9ede6c, I am trying to retrieve data from mongodb

Tags: flutter, dart

ChatRoomServices

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onpods/constants/http_error_handelling.dart';
import 'package:onpods/constants/utils.dart';
import 'package:onpods/models/chat_room_model.dart';
import 'package:onpods/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:onpods/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:onpods/view/chat_room.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../constants/global_constants.dart';

class ChatRoomServices {
  void getChatRoomIndex({
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("$uri/get-all-room-index"),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );

    print("skjnv");
    print(jsonDecode(res.body)[0]);

    List<ChatRoomModel> allChatRooms = [];

    for (var e in jsonDecode(res.body)) {
      ChatRoomModel temp = ChatRoomModel.fromJson(e.toString());
      allChatRooms.add(temp);
      print(temp.chatTopic);
      print(temp.chatTopic);
    }

    print("skjnv");

    ChatRoom chatRoom;
    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    httpErrorHandle(
      response: res,
      context: context,
      onSuccess: () async {},
    );
  }
}
```

Chat Room Model

```
import 'dart:convert';

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
class ChatRoomModel {
  String chatTopic;
  String roomType;
  Map<String, dynamic> ownerId;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> speakers;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> participants;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  ChatRoomModel({
    required this.chatTopic,
    required this.roomType,
    required this.ownerId,
    required this.speakers,
    required this.participants,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'chatTopic': chatTopic,
      'roomType': roomType,
      'ownerId': ownerId,
      'speakers': speakers,
      'participants': participants,
      'createdAt': createdAt,
      'updatedAt': updatedAt,
    };
  }

  factory ChatRoomModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ChatRoomModel(
      chatTopic: map['chatTopic'] as String,
      roomType: map['roomType'] as String,
      ownerId: Map<String, dynamic>.from((map['ownerId'] as Map<String, dynamic>)),
      speakers: List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
        (map['speakers'] as List<int>).map<Map<String, dynamic>>(
          (x) => x as Map<String, dynamic>,
        ),
      ),
      participants: List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
        (map['participants'] as List<int>).map<Map<String, dynamic>>(
          (x) => x as Map<String, dynamic>,
        ),
      ),
      createdAt: map['createdAt'] as String,
      updatedAt: map['updatedAt'] as String,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ChatRoomModel.fromJson(String source) {
    print("Sajs");
    print(source);
    return ChatRoomModel.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }
}
```

Postman request response for(/get-all-room-index)

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6414a040c01cb2fbea9ede6c",
        "chatTopic": "Current Affairs",
        "roomType": "public",
        "ownerId": {
            "isPublic": true,
            "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
            "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
            "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
            "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
            "user_role": "admin",
            "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "speakers": [
            {
                "isPublic": true,
                "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
                "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
                "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
                "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
                "user_role": "admin",
                "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "participants": [],
        "createdAt": "2023-03-17T17:15:44.873Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-03-17T17:15:44.873Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6415e11ddd95481799b016f7",
        "chatTopic": "Current Affairs",
        "roomType": "public",
        "ownerId": {
            "isPublic": true,
            "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
            "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
            "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
            "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
            "user_role": "admin",
            "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "speakers": [
            {
                "isPublic": true,
                "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
                "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
                "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
                "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
                "user_role": "admin",
                "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "participants": [],
        "createdAt": "2023-03-18T16:04:45.928Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-03-18T16:04:45.928Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Error is

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
{_id: 6414a040c01cb2fbea9ede6c, chatTopic: Current Affairs, roomType: publi...
 ^
#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:913:48)
#2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:610:36)
#4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#5      new ChatRoomModel.fromJson
chat_room_model.dart:59
#6      ChatRoomServices.getChatRoomIndex
chat_room_services.dart:33
<asynchronous suspension>
*
```

postman result

I tried changing the conversion go data types but didn't work
Can anyone please suggest me a better solution for this.
It is showing the error for _id but why i don't know.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6414a040c01cb2fbea9ede6c",
        "chatTopic": "Current Affairs",
        "roomType": "public",
        "ownerId": {
            "isPublic": true,
            "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
            "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
            "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
            "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
            "user_role": "admin",
            "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "speakers": [
            {
                "isPublic": true,
                "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
                "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
                "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
                "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
                "user_role": "admin",
                "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "participants": [],
        "createdAt": "2023-03-17T17:15:44.873Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-03-17T17:15:44.873Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6415e11ddd95481799b016f7",
        "chatTopic": "Current Affairs",
        "roomType": "public",
        "ownerId": {
            "isPublic": true,
            "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
            "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
            "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
            "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
            "user_role": "admin",
            "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "speakers": [
            {
                "isPublic": true,
                "_id": "6405fe3df459de43b5dadb78",
                "user_name": "Simran Bhalode",
                "user_email": "simran@gmail.com",
                "user_password": "$2b$07$VPHjLNYKicBcEgfyRNT9i.8zok9kU7XqNlNgnpAsZ5V9FN/oyKUka",
                "user_role": "admin",
                "registered_date": "2023-03-06T14:52:45.847Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "participants": [],
        "createdAt": "2023-03-18T16:04:45.928Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-03-18T16:04:45.928Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/discussions/1190.  The error message was identical to yours, the problem in this case was the HTTP response was HTML, instead of JSON.  However, the text you posted appears to be valid JSON.  Q: Is the text you posted from an actual HTTP response (that's giving the error)?  Q: You didn't actually post a real username and password (for the world to see), did you?

Answer (score 0):

Its a formatting error in your json to dart file id section ,use like this

```
class Autogenerated {
  String sId;
  String chatTopic;
  String roomType;
  OwnerId ownerId;
  List<Speakers> speakers;
  List<Null> participants;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  int iV;

  Autogenerated(
      {this.sId,
      this.chatTopic,
      this.roomType,
      this.ownerId,
      this.speakers,
      this.participants,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.iV});

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    chatTopic = json['chatTopic'];
    roomType = json['roomType'];
    ownerId =
        json['ownerId'] != null ? new OwnerId.fromJson(json['ownerId']) : null;
    if (json['speakers'] != null) {
      speakers = new List<Speakers>();
      json['speakers'].forEach((v) {
        speakers.add(new Speakers.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['participants'] != null) {
      participants = new List<Null>();
      json['participants'].forEach((v) {
        participants.add(new Null.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['chatTopic'] = this.chatTopic;
    data['roomType'] = this.roomType;
    if (this.ownerId != null) {
      data['ownerId'] = this.ownerId.toJson();
    }
    if (this.speakers != null) {
      data['speakers'] = this.speakers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.participants != null) {
      data['participants'] = this.participants.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['createdAt'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updatedAt'] = this.updatedAt;
    data['__v'] = this.iV;
    return data;
  }
}

class OwnerId {
  bool isPublic;
  String sId;
  String userName;
  String userEmail;
  String userPassword;
  String userRole;
  String registeredDate;
  int iV;

  OwnerId(
      {this.isPublic,
      this.sId,
      this.userName,
      this.userEmail,
      this.userPassword,
      this.userRole,
      this.registeredDate,
      this.iV});

  OwnerId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    isPublic = json['isPublic'];
    sId = json['_id'];
    userName = json['user_name'];
    userEmail = json['user_email'];
    userPassword = json['user_password'];
    userRole = json['user_role'];
    registeredDate = json['registered_date'];
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['isPublic'] = this.isPublic;
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['user_name'] = this.userName;
    data['user_email'] = this.userEmail;
    data['user_password'] = this.userPassword;
    data['user_role'] = this.userRole;
    data['registered_date'] = this.registeredDate;
    data['__v'] = this.iV;
    return data;
  }
}
```